# Twilio- Ruby get MediaUrl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am currently doing a Rails App and using the twilio-ruby gem. I want to receive mms and get the media from it. I can't seem to be able to do that. 
doing this:

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @@account_sid, @@auth_token
received_messages = client.account.messages.list(from: '+1' + @user.phone_number).first.media
```

I can see an object that is my media:

```
<Twilio::REST::Media @path=/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC6330f311971c83749025229828c5/Messages/MM0ac73682864790ec472aaace7ba/Media>
```

but to want to get the media url and put it in img tags.

Comment: `client.account.messages.list(from: '+1' + @user.phone_number).first.media.path`

Comment: yeah, I tried that too. there is no method called path

Comment: Sorry it would be if `@message=  client.account.messages.list(from: '+1' + @user.phone_number).first` `@message.media.instance_variable_get('@path')` check more on https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/blob/2b8a5b66d9e563acbbf32bc378cb7e3fa1aa29e7/spec/rest/message_spec.rb#L10

Comment: thanks this totally works. kindoff. Sometime it returns to me a <Media></Media> inside <MediaList> and sometimes not. can you explain to me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below to get the path

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new @@account_sid, @@auth_token
media = client.account.messages.list(from: '+1' + @user.phone_number).first.media

media.instance_variable_get('@path')
```